# Classcast exception while invoking findServices on ServiceManager

Tags: wso2

I am trying to use `org.wso2.carbon.registry.ws.client.registry.WSRegistryServiceClient` to create a registry object.  Objective is to look up a service with specific attribute.While trying to run the following code :

```
WSRegistryServiceClient registry = new WSRegistryServiceClient(serverURL, "admin", "admin", configContext);
    org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.services.ServiceManager serviceManager = new org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.services.ServiceManager(registry); 
        Service[] services = serviceManager.findServices(new ServiceFilter() 
        {
                public boolean matches(Service service) throws GovernanceException {
                        String attributeVal = service.getAttribute("owner_name");
                        return (attributeVal != null && attributeVal.equals("someName"));
                    }
                });
```

I get classcast exception

```
      java.lang.ClassCastException: org.wso2.carbon.registry.ws.client.registry.WSRegistryServiceClient cannot be cast to org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry exception
at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.util.GovernanceUtils.retrieveGovernanceArtifactByPath(GovernanceUtils.java:819)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.GovernanceArtifactManager.getAllGovernanceArtifacts(GovernanceArtifactManager.java:663)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.services.ServiceManager.getAllServices(ServiceManager.java:213)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.services.ServiceManager.findServices(ServiceManager.java:186)
```

WSO2's documents demonstrates adding a service using WSRegistryServiceClient but I could not find an example that demonstrates searching a service. I used the same client to search a service but it throws the above exception. What shall be the way to search a service ?

Also, Is there a way to create UserRegistry object from WSRegistryServiceClient or there are different apis to create a UserRegistry ?

Comment: Experimenting with the literature on WSO2.com. I managed to create the UserRegistry object. The way to make UserRegistry from WSRegistryServiceClient is to use GoveranceUtils class. Following is the code :

Comment: //registry refers to WSRegistryServiceClient created above and provide admin                                                  UserRegistry userRegistry = (UserRegistry) GovernanceUtils
    .getGovernanceUserRegistry(registry,
      "admin");
GovernanceUtils.loadGovernanceArtifacts(userRegistry);                          But not clear on what is a UserRegistry and why all artifacts needs to be loaded before using it.